# Add the number digits with recursion

Tags: c++

I tried to add all the digits in a number but it only adds the first and the last digit. For example `1111 -> 1+1+1+1 = 4` but I got 2, `47879 -> 35` but I got 13, and so on...

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int input(int &n)
{
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
int sum(int n, int &s)
{
    int left = n % 10;
    
    if (n < 10)
    {
        return left;
    }
    else
    { 
        s =s+ left + sum( n / 10, s);
    }
}
int main() {
    int n, s = 0;
    input(n);
    sum(n, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Also, I can only use recursion; no string, no array, no loop, etc.

Comment: Your sum() does not always return a value. I mean what does it return if (n < 10) is false?

Comment: If English is not your native language, you might not be aware that `n % 10` gives the right digit, not the left.

Comment: no, "left" means "the leftover" after you divine the number for 10, like the "left" of 123 after divine 10 is 3 :) sorry for the misunderstand

Answer (score 2):

You can use this much simpler function:

```
constexpr int sum(int n) {
  return n ? n%10 + sum(n/10) : 0;
}
```

Or if you want it to be tail-recursive:

```
int sum(int n, int s = 0) {
  return n ? sum(n/10, s + n%10) : s;
}
```

In your implementation you never return on the `else` branch.

Comment: the second code works if i change it a little bit like
```
int sum(int n, int &s ) {
    s += n % 10;
    return n ? sum(n / 10, s ) : s;
}

```
thank you, sir :))

Answer (score 2):

The function `sum` have return type of int. But in the recursion path some function calls does not return anything. (if `else` execute rather than `if`)

you can simply use this function:

```
void sum(int n, int &s)
{
    int left = n % 10;

    s += left;

    if (n < 10)
        return;
    else
        sum(n / 10, s);
}
```

Comment: your code works too, sir. You use `void` so you don't have to return the value, keep recursve the function and change the main value "&s" . I'll notice that. Thank you.:))